# How can i ping a local docker container from an outside host using macvlan network?

Tags: docker, networking, macvlan

objective : assume two hosts A & B. container x at A should be able to be pinged from host B such that this container x is present in the same network as A & B and has its own ip address.

Docker provides two types of network solutions for multi-host networking 
1) Overlay network with/without docker swarm 2) Macvlan network.
**I would like to know for the 2nd type Macvlan networks how can i achieve the objective**

Answer (score 0):

When services are running, you can attache them for debugging with

`docker exec -ti some-service.1.lz3j7mqb1ux4jp5cwe87gpiok sh`

you need to figure out the service name with `docker ps`.

Then you can try to ping another service. But this will only work when both services are attached to the same overlay network which is not ingress.

`docker network create -d overlay dev`
`docker service create --network dev --name a ...`
`docker service create --network dev --name b ...`

Then you can `ping a` from b and `ping b` from a.

Comment: your solution might be correct but as i **highlighted** in my question i am looking for a solution with Macvlan network not overlay

Answer (score 0):

Create a macvlan network called my-macvlan-net:

```
$ docker network create -d macvlan \
  --subnet=172.16.86.0/24 \
  --gateway=172.16.86.1 \
  -o parent=eth0 \
  my-macvlan-net
```

Start an example alpine container and attach it to the my-macvlan-net network:

```
$ docker run --rm -dit \
  --network my-macvlan-net \
  --name my-macvlan-alpine \
  alpine:latest \
  ash
```

Check container network settings:

```
$ docker exec my-macvlan-alpine ip addr show eth0

9: eth0@tunl0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
link/ether 02:42:ac:10:56:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.16.86.2/24 brd 172.16.86.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ docker exec my-macvlan-alpine ip route

default via 172.16.86.1 dev eth0
172.16.86.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 172.16.86.2
```

[Networking using a macvlan network](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-macvlan/)